# How to ContinueWith another function with result from previous task

Tags: c#

I have the following functions, with different return types, that I want to chain:

1. `ChrDetailedDataResponse GetChrNumberData(ChrDetailedData data)`
2. `ChrDetailedData SaveData(ChrDetailedDataResponse data)`
3. `void UpdateChrNumberLastRetrieved(int chrNumber, bool dataDownloaded)`

So far I've come up with this:

```
var firstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetChrNumberData(detailedData));

var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Result.ResultSerialized))
{
    SaveData(t.Result, detailedData);
}
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

firstTask.ContinueWith((t) => HandleTaskException(t, detailedData), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

var thirdTask = secondTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
{
UpdateChrNumberLastRetrieved(t.Result.ChrNumber, true);
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
secondTask.ContinueWith((t) => HandleTaskException(t, detailedData), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

firstTask.Start();
```

The compiler doesnt accept: `UpdateChrNumberLastRetrieved(t.Result.ChrNumber, true);` because `t.Result` does not exist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It does not exists because ```secondTask``` returns nothing

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using `async/await`? This would simplify the code *a lot*. `async/await` is available in all supported .NET frameworks (ie 4.5.2 and later)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right. Gonna switch to async/await. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using extra tasks at all if each method cannot run until the previous completes?  You're adding the overhead of managing extra tasks with no value.  You could just have one task and execute each method in order.

Comment: Good point @PeterRitchie. I might as well just have one Task that calls the methods in the order that I want. No need for extra overhead. Thanks!

Comment: That would be the fastest